# specialized UIViewController calling some method crashing iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

1. I am unable to replicate this issue, how to replicate the following fabric crash ?
2. Is there a way to open this crash in xcode (Importing crash into xcode)

   ```
   Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
   0  ABCC                           0x10092d0c4 specialized ABCViewController.signInBtnPressed(UIButton) -> ()(ABCViewController.swift:178)
   1  ABCC                           0x10092a520 @objc ABCViewController.unwind(UIStoryboardSegue) -> () + 3152641510
   2  UIKit                          0x18aced64c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
   3  UIKit                          0x18ae0e870 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 52
   4  UIKit                          0x18acf3700 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 120
   5  UIKit                          0x18ae291a8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 492
   6  UIKit                          0x18b2ceee8 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 4340
   7  UIKit                          0x18b2cbc60 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1236
   8  UIKit                          0x18ad664d8 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404
   9  UIKit                          0x18ad66010 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 276
   10 UIKit                          0x18ad65874 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3132
   11 UIKit                          0x18ad641d0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
   12 UIKit                          0x18b545d1c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2340
   13 UIKit                          0x18b5482c8 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4744
   14 CoreFoundation                 0x180f27404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
   15 CoreFoundation                 0x180f26c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
   16 CoreFoundation                 0x180f2479c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
   17 CoreFoundation                 0x180e44da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
   18 GraphicsServices               0x182e2a020 GSEventRunModal + 100
   19 UIKit                          0x18ae64758 UIApplicationMain + 236
   20 ABCC                           0x1007b28c4 main (main.m:20)
   21 libdyld.dylib                  0x1808d5fc0 start + 4
   ```

Here is the code for the action that is crashing.

```
@IBAction func signInBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    guard let employees = UserService.shared.employees, let name = employees.names?[sender.tag] else {
        sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true  // crashing here
        return
    }
    // perform task
    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Provide specific code

Comment: The crash is happening at line 178 of `ABCViewController`. You need to see what's going on there.

Comment: Add code for `signInBtnPressed` method in `ABCViewController`

Comment: Yes, added code and crashing at `guard else` loop, do anyone of you think `sender` can ever be nil ?

Comment: Do you have more than one action on the button in the storyboard? Looks like it's trying to do an unwind segue at the same time as running this function?

Comment: Have you checked whether you have passed a nil value of sender?  You could have fooled the compiler by using signInButtonPressed(sender!).  The compiler would accept the nil value and fail when trying to dereference it at the first line. -- Maybe try printing the value out before using it....

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes your correct, It is a collection cells which has sign in button for each cell.

Comment: @DrPhill I did check the sender value, didn't observe any nil case.

Comment: The button should only have one action assigned to it. If you want something to happen after running the function then do it in code.

Comment: OK, simple ideas gone.  Now for complex ones:  Could you be accidentally accidentally accessing deallocated memory? Tricky one to find, but the symptoms can be bizarre. Only way I know to tackle this is by running with zombies enabled. Good luck!

Comment: @Fogmeister button has only one action. Multiple collection view cells with a button assigned to each cell.

Comment: @DrPhill I have that doubt but it is highly impossible I guess.